# Creating mock data object for angular application using typescript

Tags: angular

I am building an angular reactive form and have kendodropdownlists. I need to create a dummy structure of data and bind said data to my angular form.

There will be an object called `FirmDetails` which would contain the object Firm. The `firm object` will contain following fields and collection called `Addresses`. I need to create this structure and assign values to it.

**So ultimately data will contain the structure and values for FirmDetails:**

```
this.FirmDetails = data;



FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
 FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
 FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE1,
 FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE2,
 FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE3,
 FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].SWITCHBOARD_INT
```

**What I have created is:**

```
const FirmDetails = {

    Firm: {
        NAME: 'Jack',
        SHORT_NAME: ‘Mayne’
        ADDRESSES: {
            LINE1: 'westwish st',
            LINE2: 'washmasher',
            LINE3: 'wallas',
            SWITCHBOARD_INT: 164356
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create addresses as it’s s collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define it as an array of objects:

```
const FirmDetails = {
   Firm: {
      NAME: 'Jack',
      SHORT_NAME: ‘Mayne’,
      ADDRESSES: [
         {
            LINE1: 'westwish st',
            LINE2: 'washmasher',
            LINE3: 'wallas',
            SWITCHBOARD_INT: 164356
         },
         {
            LINE1: 'bla bla',
            LINE2: 'bla',
            LINE3: 'bla bla bla',
            SWITCHBOARD_INT: 56052
         }
      ]
   }
}
```